# How to always have the token:github.com credential written in git config file by default, whenever cloning a repository?

Tags: git

I have a couple of remote servers (one server per repository) that I develop on (using VS Code and its [ssh capability](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)) and I was trying to figure out why I had no problem pushing changes to one repo from one server, and why my other server always requested me for my password.

On the server where everything was and is ok,

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe@github.com/me/repo1.git (fetch)
origin  https://ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe@github.com/me/repo1.git (push)
```

Running `git push origin master` returns no errors and works just fine.

On the server where I kept getting prompted for my token (which I wrote out above):

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/me/repo2.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/me/repo2.git (push)
```

On this server, whenever I ran `git push origin master`, it prompted me as so:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe
Password for 'https://ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe@github.com':
```

So, following the breadcrumbs, I ran the following on the server where everything was ok:

```
$ cat ./.git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe@github.com/me/repo1.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I did the same on the other server and noticed that the `url` is different. So using this information, on that server I ran the following:

```
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin https://ghp_AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqEe@github.com/me/repo2.git
```

This solved my problem, but how can I get this to work from the get go? When I clone one of my repositories, how can I ensure that this will be the setup? I don't want to remove and then re-add origins manually like this.

Comment: Use a [credential helper](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git). Note that there are tabs to switch OS on the page. It's not a good idea to write the password/token in the url.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub requires additional authentication through http/s that tends to be unreliable and a mess of usernames and passwords.

It has also been deprecated for a while now,so I don't really know how you're using it...

You should try to set up ssh keys for account/project, which handle authentication by nature, try this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Some directions:

- If your identity is the same on both the server and your machine (you're just accessing the repo on multiple places), you should just share the keys between them. However, if you're concerned about the key security, make different keys and add them to your account.
- If the identity is different (like collaborating with another person through the server), make sure the keys are added to every person's account (so GitHub accepts its use) and set up proper access rules on the repository.
- About the ssh key, most of the time it's under `~/.ssh` (depends on the software you're using), and it's usually encrypted with a passphrase, if you want to avoid prompts without losing the security of the passphrase, you might want to set up ssh-agent. (this applies for Linux, macOS might be somewhat similar and windows likely has it's own thing or have Linux adapted for it)

Comment: I'm not using a username and password, I'm using a [personal access to token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) :) I've indicated that in my question. Your answer also doesn't really answer my question, I'm already doing most of what you've laid out on other servers. I was just curious about my current situation with these two specific servers of mine